# How to remove focus from textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When opening form the cursor is waiting in the text box along with help text.So there are some validation error happening. So i don't want focus when opening form, user have to click the text and type the text. But here didn't any onfocus eventhough cursor in the textbox .

```
if(!$.trim($("#productsTextArea1").val())){
        helpTip = "help string ....";
        $("#productsTextArea1").val(helpTip);
        $("#productsTextArea1").css("color","#999");
        $("#productsTextArea1").click(function(event){
            if($("#productsTextArea1").val().indexOf("Enter a return")>-1){
                $("#productsTextArea1").css("color","black").val("");
            }
        });
    } else {
         $("#productsTextArea1").blur();
    }
```

Please advise...

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AVbJk/)

Comment: Why are you running this function on page load? Why not defer it until the user actually clicks on the textarea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UPDATE:

Use HTML5 Placeholder attribute, you don't need to use any js.

```
    <textarea id="productsTextArea1" name="product" rows="5" 
placeholder="Some Hint Text is Placed Here"></textarea>
```

To disable autofocus on all input elements use this.

```
  $(function(){
        $('input').blur();
    });
```

To disbale autofocus on a particular element, pass the element id as below:

```
$(function(){
    $('input#someid').blur();
});
```

Comment: Actually there is no autofocus, what are you asking.Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Correct , there is no autofocus in the code but once page loads the cursor is waiting in the textarea , How is happening ? Please check the jsfiddle which i given.

Comment: It works fine for me. I see no autofocus and focus is only appearing when you click inside textarea. For me all is working as it should be. I tested in Firefox and Chrome. Which browser are you testing? Everything looks fine for me..

Comment: Attached the screen shot and i'm checking firefox 22.Please check the issue here http://jsfiddle.net/AVbJk/ - down the scroll bar and will see the cursor.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, As I said it works fine for me. However why don't you try using html5 placeholder attribute as in my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/AVbJk/18/

You really don't need to use that script anymore or any js for that matter.

Comment: This issue can be consistently reproduced in IE.